# How to sql pivot

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE #yt
    ([AtiviteID] int, [Resim1] int, [Resim2] int)
;

INSERT INTO #yt
    ([AtiviteID], [Resim1], [Resim2])
VALUES
    (1, NULL, 11),
    (1, 22, 33),
    (1, 44, NULL),
    (2, 55, 66),
    (2, 77, 88)
;



  select AtiviteID, Resim1, Resim2
  from #yt
```

how list

```
AktiviteID Resim
1           11
1           22
1           33
1           44
2           55
2           66
2           77
2           88
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unpivot

```
 select AtiviteID,Resism from 
(
select * from #yt
)
src unpivot
(
Resism for res in (Resim1,Resim2)
) up

AtiviteID   Resism
    1        11
    1        22
    1        33
    1        44
    2        55
    2        66
    2        77
    2        88
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8d4f65a41c2fda159ba192965099369e)

Answer (score 0):

You need `unpivot` rather than `pivot`, so i would use `apply` :

```
select yt.AtiviteID, yt1.Resim
from #yt yt cross apply
    ( values (Resim1), (Resim2) ) yt1 (Resim)
where yt1.Resim is not null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help,  I have one more question

select AktiviteID, Resim
from #yt where AktiviteID=1 yt cross apply
    ( values (Resim1), (Resim2) ) yt1 (Resim) how to

Comment: @MehmetYAVUZ. . . Your `where` clause should go after `cross apply`.